# Handlebars and JWT token to local storage

Tags: express, handlebars.js, local-storage, jwt, express-handlebars

I am using express-handlebars and jwt tokens for a login route. I am trying to store the token in local storage upon hitting a login route on my api. The problem is when I set the token in the front end it creates an error due to its format. My code is below and if anyone has a fix or ideas that would be great. Thanks!
Front end: (in handlebars template)

```
{{#if auth.token}}
<script type="text/javascript" async>
const token = {{auth.token}};
localStorage.setItem("token", token)
</script>
{{/if}}
```

Backend, saving token and sending with render:

```
jwt.sign(
              payload,
              keys.JWT_KEY,
              { expiresIn: 3600 },
              (err, token) => {
                auth.token = token;
                auth.status = true;
                res.render("home", { auth: auth });
              }
            );
```

The error is Syntax error: invalid or unexpected token.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is breaking is because you're trying to set the variable `token` in the handlebars template equal to the literal token. It would be the equivalant of doing something like:

```
var token = gmndshhrjvjhsw4bnds221a
```

Which doesn't work. You need to turn it into a string by wrapping it in double or single-quotes.

This is the correct code for what you're trying to do:

```
{{#if auth.token}}
  <script type="text/javascript" async>
    const token = '{{auth.token}}';
    localStorage.setItem("token", token)
  </script>
{{/if}}
```